# load / set php class var names dynamic ->{$}

Tags: php, class

How i can set php class var names dynamic?

Example:

```
$var_name = "new_var";
$class->{$var_name} = "new value";
```

It's ok?

Comment: -1 Try it, don't use Stack Overflow as if it were Google.

Comment: thx for down voting! i tried it in various examples and just wanted to ask whether it would be the best solution! I lern php and can ask for best solution or not ?!

Comment: You didn't ask if it's the best solution. Neither did you point out the things you have tried. Stack Overflow has rules about what should be included in a question read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Also you should be aware that down voting is not a personal thing, it's a mechanism that Stack Overflow uses to improve the quality of the Questions/Answers and to encourage users to improve their Questions/Answers. If you update your Question I'll up vote.

Answer (score 1):

```
$class->$var_name = "new value";
```

http://codepad.org/KKAwSQdA

Comment: thx, but it works only for string values and not for array entries... like $array = array(1,2,3); $class->$var_name['array'] = $array;

Comment: You never asked about arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's ok. Have you at least tried?

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php